# How to conditionally format in LaTeX?

Tags: conditionals

I am interested in formatting the following code such that if a conditional is met (Add = 0 and Del = 0), then my document prints out "There are no additions or deletions". Otherwise, the document prints out a bulleted list with the values of Add and Del.

```
AddName = 0
DelName = 0
cat("\\newcommand{\\Add}{",AddName,"}",sep="")
cat("\\newcommand{\\Delete}{",DelName,"}",sep="")

\if <\Add = 0 AND \Del = 0> 
  <\normal{There are no additions or deletions.}>
\fi

\begin{compactitem}
    \item[$\bullet$ \Add { } {\color{OliveGreen}\bf{+}}:]
    \item[$\bullet$ \Del { } {\color{red}\bf{-}}:]
\end{compactitem}
```

I could not find too much documentation online, and here are the error messages I get:

```
> \if <\Add = 0 AND \Del = 0> 
Error: unexpected input in "\"
>   <\normal{There are no additions or deletions.}>
Error: unexpected '<' in "  <"
> \fi
Error: unexpected input in "\"

> \begin{compactitem}
Error: unexpected input in "\"
> \item[$\bullet$ \Add { } {\color{OliveGreen}\bf{+}}:]
Error: unexpected input in "\"
> \item[$\bullet$ \Del { } {\color{red}\bf{-}}:]
Error: unexpected input in "\"
> \end{compactitem}
Error: unexpected input in "\"
```

Can someone please help me debug these errors?

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at the `ifthen` package and booleans in LaTeX. It is easy to setup `\ifthenelse{\boolean{add}\AND\boolean{del}}{}{}`.

Comment: Btw: `<` and `>` should only be used in math mode or something `\ifnum` like.

Comment: @TeXnician it is not mentioned anywhere but based on previous questions i assume that this is R syntax not tex (the error messages do not come from tex either)